# Simple Bar Plot in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph, bar-chart

I am trying to plot a simple `bar plot` for a `keyword vs frequency` list. 
As the data does not have `header` I am unable to use `Pandas` or `Seabron.`

Input

```
#kyuhyun,1
#therinewyear,4
#lingaa,2
#starts,1
#inox,1
#arrsmultiplex,1
#bollywood,1
#kenya,1
#time,1
#watch,1
#malaysia,3
```

Code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import*
import numpy as np 

x,y = np.genfromtxt('theri_split_keyword.csv', delimiter = ',', unpack=True, comments=None, usecols=(0,1))

plt.bar(x,y)

plt.title('Info')
plt.ylabel('Y axis')
plt.xlabel('X axis')

plt.show()
```

all I am trying to plot is a bar graph with `x axis` as the keywords and `y axis` for the frequency. Any easy method to plot this will be huge help.

The Output I am getting is below, which is definitely NOT what I am looking for. 
[image]

The solution below seems to be working like a charm but I have too many keywords in a list and I am looking for a choice like if I can plot only top 10-20 keywords with respective keywords so that the bar plots will look much nicer.

Output of the solution given in answers.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import csv

    x = []
    y = []
    with open('theri_split_keyword.csv', "rb") as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        for row in reader:
            x.append(row[0].lstrip('#'))
            y.append(int(row[1]))

    ind = np.arange(len(x))  # the x locations for the groups
    width = 0.35       # the width of the bars

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    plt.bar(ind,y)

    ax.set_ylabel('Y axis')
    ax.set_title('X axis')
    ax.set_xticks(ind + width)
    ax.set_xticklabels(x, rotation='vertical')


    plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi .. Thank you for the working solution. But I seem to have a problem here the list of keywords is too large is their any way I can take may be top 10 - 20 keywords and the respect frequencies. I am including the final plot in the edit. Pls suggest if thr is any such option to choose top keywords.

Comment: @SitzBlogz: If you have an additional question, please post it as a separate question; and if this answered your original question, please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Not answering your question, but pandas does not require data to have a header. 
If you read data from file, just select header=None (more info [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)).

```
df = pd.read_csv(myPath, header=None)
df.columns = ('word','freq') # my cystom header
df.set_index('word') # not neccesary but will provide words as ticks on the plot
df.plot(kind='bar')
```

you can also pass data as a dictionary, for example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'word':['w1','w2','w3'],'freq':[1,2,3})
df.plot.bar()
```

Comment: Could you please help with full code to get some idea about how I can read columns using pandas when I have no headers

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `np.genfromtxt` but I suspect the problem is that it returns `x` as an array of strings when `x` should be numerical.

maybe try something like:

```
tick_marks = np.arange(len(x))
plt.bar(tick_marks, y)
plt.xticks(tick_marks, x, rotation=45)
```